# Are these boxing/unboxing examples

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

Are 2 and 3 boxing/unboxing examples?

**1) The documentation example:**

```
int i = 123;
object iBoxed = i;
i = (int) iBoxed;
```

**2: Is the boxing/unboxing as well?**

```
int i = 123;
object iBoxed = i;
i = Int32.Parse(iBoxed.ToString());
```

**3: Is the boxing/unboxing as well?**

```
int i = 123;
object iBoxed = i;
i = Convert.ToInt32(iBoxed);
```

I assume that in all examples technically happens the same.

1. A value type is created on the stack
2. A reference is created on the stack, the value is copied to the heap.
3. The heap value is copied to the reference. The reference gets deleted.

So I guess 2 und 3 are examples for boxing/unboxing?

Comment: i think so, since you put int in an object "box" and then you retireve it form that box. The idea behind box and unbox is to change a value type to a reference type and back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all three examples:

`iBoxed` is a boxed copy of `i`.

In example 2:
There is no unboxing involved here, as `ToString` is a virtual method that will finally resolve to `int.ToString`, which will then be parsed by `int.Parse`, returning a non-boxed `int` on the stack.

In example 3:
`iBoxed` will get unboxed in the body of the method `Convert.ToInt32` and returned as a non-boxed integer, on the stack again.

Comment: I fixed example 2, which didn't compile anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The second example is boxing but not unboxing.  The int.parse won't compile because it expects a string and iBoxed is an object.  I think you are mixing the concepts of boxing and conversion.  Boxing is really about taking a value type ie POD as they say in C and treating it as reference unboxing is the ability to extract that same value type out of its container.

Ex 2.  Fixed

```
int i = 123;  // Assigment 
object iBoxed = i ; // This is boxing 
i = int.parse(iBoxed.toString());  //This is unboxing but only for the twostring method the assignment is a value type copy.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `object iBoxed = i` which do the boxing.

Example 2 wont work since `int.Parse` expects a string

Answer (score 0):

In all your examples, the value type `i` is being converted to an object.  This is the definition of boxing according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).  Boxing could also be done by:

```
object boxed = (object)i;
```

The unboxing is the conversion of the object back to a value type.
Example 1 is unboxing

Example 2 will fail to compile because `Parse` expects a `string` argument but would be unboxing if you did `iBoxed.ToString()`

Example 3 i suspect is not unboxing because the `Convert` method will just return the value that you pass in.

Its worth being aware of the performance hit of boxing and unboxing.  It is more expensive than normal assignment.